# Add column to table with set values for every row expanding the table

Tags: sql, amazon-redshift, cross-join

I'm trying to add a column to a table in Redshift that adds multiple values to all the rows but has no relation, apart from all rows should be affected.

I'm not sure how to describe this so Google-ing is proving tough!

Visual example:

```
+----+-------+
| ID | Name  |
+----+-------+
|  1 | James |
|  2 | Jane  |
+----+-------+
```

Should become

```
+----+-------+-----+
| ID | Name  | Sec |
+----+-------+-----+
|  1 | James | SG1 |
|  1 | James | SG2 |
|  1 | James | SG3 |
|  2 | Jane  | SG1 |
|  2 | Jane  | SG2 |
|  2 | Jane  | SG3 |
+----+-------+-----+
```

Basically added "SG1, SG2, and SG3" to every row.

Thanks,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can `cross join` a derived table that contains the three values:

```
select t.id, t.name, s.sec
from mytable t
cross join (select 'SG1' sec union all select 'SG2' union all select 'SG3') s
```

I am unsure whether Redshift supports `values()`, which would help shortening the syntax:

```
select t.id, t.name, s.sec
from mytable t
cross join (values ('SG1'), ('SG2'), ('SG3')) s(sec)
```

Comment: Values isnt supported it seems but the top answer worked perfect. Thank you.